# Stuck finding the area of a region for $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|9\sin{x}-9\cos{2x}|dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm so frustrated with this problem!  I've spent maybe an hour on it just making sure I have everything perfect since the first couple of times I kept getting it incorrect.

Can you spot my error?

This is the original equation:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|9\sin(x)-9\cos(2x)|dx$$

After doing some factoring and trig identity substitution I came up with the following integrals:

$$9\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\cos(2x) - \sin(x)dx + 9\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(x) - \cos(2x)dx$$

And then I anti-differentiated:

$$9(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+\cos(x))|_{0}^{{\pi}{6}}+9(-\cos(x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x))|_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{pi}{2}$$

"Simplifying" I got this:

$$\frac92\sin\left(2\frac\pi6\right)+9\cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)-[\frac92\sin(2\cdot0)+9\cos(0)]-9\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)-\frac92\sin(\pi)-[-9\cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)-\frac92\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)]$$

Simplifying even further I got this (this is where I suspect I messed up):

$$\frac{9\sqrt3}4+\frac{9\sqrt3}2-[0+9]-0+\frac92-[-\frac{9\sqrt3}2-\frac{9\sqrt3}4]$$

I got a final answer of:

$$\frac{9\sqrt3}2+9\sqrt3+\frac92-9$$

Please help me :(

Comment: $ \ \frac{9}{2} \cdot \sin \pi = \ $ ?!

Comment: @RecklessReckoner $\frac{-9}{2}$?

Comment: Sine of pi is what?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner omg.. it's `0`

Comment: Quite so...  Does that fix things?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!  Math can be so frustrating... it took me so long to get the problem put together and I can't believe I made such a small mistake (one that I normally make with trig).

Comment: As my old section supervisor would say to me (many years ago now -- with a straight face), "No one has _ever_ made that mistake before..."  Little things like that happen to **everyone** doing math at one time or another -- there's no shame in it.  I'm glad that helped.  [Take consolation in the fact that you actually did all the **hard** parts of the calculation _correctly!_]

Comment: Thanks and now I will remember that statement that your supervisor told you!

Comment: Just a couple of suggestions for the future (from one whose computational errors are piled really high, and who has therefore learned to be both careful and tricky).  You had a factor of 9 in everything.  You can ignore that until you've computed the rest of the problem then multiply it back in.  If you can ever find a 0 or a 1, as per RecklessR, that helps, so look for them.  Finally, I would not convert the sin and cos values until the very end.  If you leave them in sin and cos form you can see cancellations very easily -- and you want all of those you can get.

Comment: The Maple command $$int(abs(9*sin(x)-9*cos(2*x)), x = 0 .. (1/2)*Pi) $$ produces $$-9+{\frac {27}{2}}\,\sqrt {3} .$$